# What's a good, generic name for chart of things by time of day?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

We're creating a chart showing traffic by time of day over a given period. So the y-axis is traffic, the x-axis is midnight, 1am, 2am, etc. It could also be days of the week. What's the generic name for this type of chart? I've come up with "cycle chart". Is that the standard? Is there one?
[image: example]

Update:

Just to add a bit more clarity, what's being shown in the top chart is *not* one day, it's an aggregation of many days. E.g. over the last month, 6am has on average been lower than noon. Similarly, in the bottom chart, over the last year, traffic dips on Saturdays.

Comment: oh, great. now the sketch is there. :)

Comment: 'Periodic chart'?

Comment: @onestop: that's a decent alternative to "cyclic". If you turn the comment into an answer, I might give it to you.

Comment: An aside: Sometimes it is better to plot this kind of chart around a circle. For example, there might be an interesting pattern from 10pm to 2am, but, the way that your chart is cut at midnight, you might not notice this pattern. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076370/most-underused-data-visualization/2083230#2083230

Comment: @Charlie an alternative that is often easier to both plot and read is to repeat part of the data and plot a bit more than a complete period, e.g. to plot over 30 hours from midnight to midnight and on to 6am, so the info from midnight to 6am appears twice - much as New Zealand or Alaska appear twice on some maps. I got this idea via Stata guru Nick Cox but I can't find the ref at present. [Tukey (1972)](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/tukey) favoured two complete cycles.

Comment: An example of some of the circle charts in R, http://goo.gl/WoyVp . I agree with onestop's point as well though and is probably just as easy if not easier to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nick Cox [(*Stata Journal* 2006, p403)](http://stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0025) calls this sort of plot a **'cycle plot'**, but notes that:

> Cycle plots have been discussed under other names in the literature, including cycle-subseries plot, month plot, seasonal-by-month plot, and seasonal subseries plot.

(followed by a load of refs to textbooks and papers)

Many of these are clearly specific to seasonality, i.e. periods of one year. I still like the suggestion of 'periodic plot/chart' that I made in a comment to the question, but it appears the questioner's original suggestion of 'cycle plot/chart' is in fact the more standard generic term.

Comment: Even though we wound up going with histogram in case we decide to do other kinds of similar charts that aren't time related, I think this is the most direct answer to the question that I asked. (We're actually using histogram/time, but maybe I'll change it to histogram/cycle....)

Answer (score 4):

What you've illustrated is a time series column (or bar) graph. The two graphs are of differing time resolution or differing time aggregation.

There may be industry specific terms for these types of charts. In finance, for example, the [open-high-low-close chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-high-low-close_chart) is a very common time series plot:

[image]

When the x axis is time, as in your example, it's often common to illustrate the points as a line graph, instead of bars/columns. The reason for this is to put the visual emphasis on the change from one period to the next.

You might also consider graphing period-over-period. For example a [year-over-year](http://spotfire.tibco.com/community/blogs/stn/archive/2009/01/28/create-a-year-over-year-comparison-chart.aspx) would show how the numbers for a given month (typically, although could be month or day) compare to the numbers of the prior year for the same month.

[image]

But I realize your question was about naming, not all the other cool graphs you can do ;)

Comment: The point of the question seems to be that the x-axis summarizes a *periodic* or *cyclic* variable.

Comment: @whuber: yup! (thanks for the detailed answer, though, JD)

Comment: doh! thanks @whuber, I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest "diurnal" or "circadian" rhythm chart. For weekly, the latter would be "circaseptan", "circamensual" for "monthly", and "circannual" for "yearly".

Comment: those are all cool, but I was looking for something for the whole class of charts. We went with histogram....

Answer (score 0):

The type of chart you've drawn is known as a Histogram http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram

Comment: Being picky: A histogram never has blank spaces between the bars. When it does it is called a bar chart

Comment: @os @Ralph A *histogram* represents probability (or frequency) by means of graphical *area,* whereas a "bar chart" (which is what we're looking at here) uses *length*.  Of course histograms can have blank spaces between bars, when there's no probability or frequency there!

Comment: I take back my earlier comment. Given what I now realize from the discussion, this could be a histogram showing frequency by time or day buckets.

Comment: as I said on Owe's answer, I think technically, this is correct, but a name that indicates the relationship to time would be nice.

Comment: A histogram displays the distribution of a continuous variable.  A bar chart displays the distribution of a discrete variable.

Comment: @whuber - I'm not clear. Are we being picky because the OP's diagram was drawn with no marked frequency on the y-axis? My point was that if you do a Google search, you will see many definitions of "Histogram" which adamantly insist that the bars never touch. In practice, it really does not make a difference, but most published histograms will show the bars adjacent. – Ralph Winters 0 secs ago edit

Comment: @Ralph I wouldn't waste time being picky :-).  The difference between a bar chart and a histogram is fundamental, but it's not surprising that the Web is full of confusion on this point because superficially the two look similar.  Please refer to a reputable textbook, such as the Freedman, Pisani, & Purves *Statistics* (any edition).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Short, simple, descriptive: time series plot.</strike>

Edit: In light of the discussion, I'd vote for histogram as well. At least, thats the generic name for this kind of chart, where the hours of the day are a natural division of stacks.

Comment: to me, "time series" implies either a cycle, or linear time. I'm interested in something specific to cyclic data.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood your question - so the data is aggregated over the hours of a day, or or the days of the week for a number of days or weeks? In that case it is a kind of histogram.

Comment: hmm... I think you're correct (looking at the wiki entry on histogram), but ideally something specific to time would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your charts are a diurnal hourly-average bar chart, and a one-week daily-average bar chart, respectively.